# Will it have any performance issues or is the right approach with REDIS or not?

Tags: redis, node-redis

Is it the right way if I save json in redis by applying JSON.stringifiy(), and on retrieve apply JSON.parse().

Q) Do it has some performance issues while writing and retrieving, consider array of records? Or its not even basically the right approach with redis?

Just to stackoverflow, curious to know the best practices with redis.

Comment: Do you need to just store/load the all JSON or also need to update part of it or retrieve a portion?

Comment: @GuyKorland good question well what if yes or what if not?

Comment: If you always need to retrieve and store full JSON then you should use the method you mentioned in the question, if you need more try using the Redis Module, RedisJSON (https://redisjson.io)

Comment: Thanks for telling about RedisJSON, else I was thinking of JSON.stringify/ JSON.parse as I said, that might take up few cpu cycles, will check for RedisJSON.